# Envelope distort with top object doesn't give the expected result

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, cs6, illustrator-effects

i am trying to curve a text to this shape:

[image]

somewhat like this but with the sides smaller, like in the shape.

[image]

What i mean is i want it to only wrap like an arc and not like a ballon or so (no 3d?). But i end up getting this result: What am i doing wrong?

[image]

Here is the link with the file. Also im using CS6. https://filebin.net/k0qqg0yx94a0xa0i

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Your shape (top object) has *waaaaaay* too many anchor points. Clean it up so there are only 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's already commented that your envelope is too complex. I tried to draw a simpler envelope, but the result was still a mess. The resulted distortion of complex shapes like your text isn't easily predictable.

**A workaround:**

Drag your text to the Brushes collection and define it to be an Art brush:

[image]

In the left there's your text (actually an outline image)

In the middle there's a drawn curve and the new art brush applied to the same curve

In the right the width tool is applied to the curved text image for thicker mid part.

**Workaround 2**: Make the envelope distortion with warp (=arc) and edit the result with the direct selection tool. Here's one attempt. Your magenta shape was placed under the work, but it's moved aside to show the mesh:

[image]